# Google Maps API V3 managing multiple markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a location reference page using Google maps API V3 and there will be about 30 markers. I am not sure if its a good idea to have all the markers on the html page that will be hosted or if it should be stored in a different location. Also including the marker information (description).

I've found the code for multiple markers using Google Maps API V3 and modified it using Google's own reference. Here is the code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var infoString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Auckland 6625</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
      'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
      'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
      'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
      '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
      'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
      'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
      'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
      'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
      'Heritage Site.</p>'+
      '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
      'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
      '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>'


    var locations = [
      [infoString, -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-39.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;
    var markers = new Array();

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }

    function AutoCenter() {
      //  Create a new viewpoint bound
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      //  Go through each...
      $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
      bounds.extend(marker.position);
      });
      //  Fit these bounds to the map
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
    AutoCenter();

  </script>
```

Since marker info (description) is going to be long, (not as long as the shown above) I am thinking of creating a variable for each marker.

So I am not sure if this is the most efficient way to do this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inefficient with the way you're doing it right now.  There's no real advantage though in having each description as a separate variable, you may as well just make it part of your `locations` variable from the beginning.  Unless perhaps you were getting the data from somewhere else (e.g. an ajax request) that you could then add into `location`.

The only real change I'd make would be instead of having a 2D array, I'd make it a 1D array of objects.

```
var locations = [
  {
    description: infoString, 
    lat: -33.890542, 
    lng: 151.274856, 
    foo: 4
  },
  {description: 'Coogee Beach', lat: -33.923036, lng: 151.259052, foo: 5},
  {description: 'Cronulla Beach', lat: -34.028249, lng: 151.157507, foo: 3},
  {description: 'Manly Beach', lat: -33.80010128657071, lng: 151.28747820854187, foo: 2},
  {description: 'Maroubra Beach', lat: -33.950198, lng: 151.259302, foo: 1}
];

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].lng),
    map: map
  });

  markers.push(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i].description);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```